# Replacement for java reflection in method overloading

Tags: java, reflection, overloading

I have a following class hierarchy:

```
<code>
public interface Decorator <T> {
    T decorate(String data);
}
public class StringDecorator implements Decorator<String> {
    @Override
    public String decorate(String data) {
        return "Decorated Data";
    }
}
public class IntegerDecorator implements Decorator<Integer> {
    @Override
    public Integer decorate(String data) {
        return 0;
    }
}
public class MyPrint {
    public void printData(String data) {
        System.out.println("String Data: " + data);
    }
    public void printData(Integer data) {
        System.out.println("Integer Data: " + data);
    }
}
</code>
```

With the above structure in place, I want to first call some decorator function and pass the same result to printData method. Currantly I'm able to achieve this with the help of java reflection as follows:

```
<code>
void callerFunction(Decorator decorator, MyPrint myPrint){
    // Below line would call appropriate decorator depending on injected type
    Object decoratedData = decorator.decorate("test");
    try {
        // Java reflection to figure out an appropriate overloaded method to be invoked
        myPrint.getClass().getMethod("printData", decoratedData.getClass()).invoke(myPrint, decoratedData);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
</code>
```

Is there any better way to achieve the same without using reflection? The use case is to call appropriate printData overloaded function depending on the type of data that decorator returns (without using if else on instanceOf).

Thanks.

Comment: This is most certainly not a correct implementation of a Decorator, but the good news is, this problem doesn't call for a Decorator.

Comment: Could be a job for Visitor.

Comment: Yah may be a bad naming convention there. Let's just say that the decorator hierarchy in above problem actually processes the data in one or the other way.. Some kind of processor may be.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two solutions.

Firstly you could not bother with overloading printData and instead rely on defining a suitable toString method in each class:

```
 public void printData(Object data) {
    System.out.println("Data: " + data);
}
```

Secondly you could define a print data method using generics, eg within each decorator

```
public interface Decorator <T> {
    T decorate(String data);
    void printData(T object);
}
```

Or equivalently you could define a separate printData interface and then whatever is crating your decorator classes would also have to create a corresponding printData class.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply Matt.. The first one with 'Object' wouldn't work in my case as I want to perform different operations depending on the type of the data.

Also, as you said, using hierarchy for both functions with generics would work. But wanted to see if there's an option where one can use overloading for this. Because I already have a different hierarchy in place for myPrint  which is like mailPrint and filePrint.

Comment: Fair enough. You're a bit stuck in that case. Overloading isn't going to work because the overloaded method is determined at compile time based in the object type. As t he compiler only has an Object there is no way for it to decide which method to call.